# Is there a way to change frames in the Internet Explorer script console?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, script-console

In Google Chrome's Dev tools there's a simple dropdown to choose which window you want to execute your script in:

[image]

Is there an equivalent in Internet Explorer?  I'm trying to run scripts from the console as if they're from an iframe, not the toplevel window.

Comment: He's asking for a convenience feature in IE.. Hahahaha.      Sorry... Had another 4 hour "Damn-IE-is-not-working-while-every-other-browser-is" session today...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible, however it’s significantly less convenient than in Chrome.

If you’re able to get a reference to the frame or its `window` object (using, e.g.:  `document.getElementById(xxx).contentWindow`), you can use the console’s special `cd` function. This is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx#UsingCDacrossFrames

Annoyingly, this means that if you want to get a reference to a nested iframe, you have to do this inside each each of the parents of the frame that you’re interested in. Debugging in IE is, erm, fun.

Comment: Note that this only works in IE 9 or greater. There doesn't appear to be a way to do this in IE 8 unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

To follow-up on [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13707930/41153), that would be

```
cd([reference])
```

or

```
cd(frames[n])
```

where `n` is a valid index in the window.frames array

Answer (score 2):

The feature is now available in IE 11. If you open the dev tools (F12) there's a combo-box in the top right that lets you select the target frame.

[image: Internet Explorer 11 Dev Tools Target Frame combobox]

(Note: this is on IE 11.0.9600.17728, not sure if every version of IE 11 has it.)

Answer (score 0):

F12 -> script -> choose your page -> console

EDIT:

You can start debug there on java script, add break point and stuff. your keys to run the debugger is like in visual studio.

Comment: The first method doesn't work for me. Ben's `cd` function below is rock-solid, however.